# Bootstrap aligning horizontal form & button

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been stuck adding the finishing touches to my first web development project. This is my first time using bootstrap and I've spent a few hours reading posts and articles to no success. I've posted my html snippet along with related css code that I've tried.

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="search">
        <div class="col-lg-12"> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Calendar">
                <!--<span class="input-group-addon"> -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                <!--</span>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-lg-7{
    float: left;
}

.col-lg-7 .form-horizontal{
    width:80%;
    float:left;
}

.col-lg-12 .form-group .form-control .{
    float:left;
}
```

I don't quite understand why my search form and button class aren't aligning. Is there a clearfix for bootstrap classes? I've tried floating everything left as you can see, but this does't solve me problem. You will also see that I attempted to use the input-group-addon class as well; however, this made my search form look like it was vertical, not horizontal.

If anyone could lead me in the right direction in would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap button group with addons.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
           </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsbin.com/quwasitane/edit?html,css,output

Hope it works fine for you!!!!

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This was exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Great deal of help my friend!

Comment: Thats ok friend, let me know if you need any other help in this.

Answer (score 0):

try class form-inline

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
                <form class="form-inline" role="search">
                    <div class="col-lg-12"> 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Calendar">
                            <!--<span class="input-group-addon"> -->
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                            <!--</span>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

comment out css for now, bootstrap will have the css required

Comment: Thank you so much! I've realized that the css has really been my biggest pain point. Since posting, I've restarted from scratch using strictly bootstrap and everything is going much smoother. Your fix aligned my search button with my form; however, now the two together only take up about 2 grid columns. Any clue why this would be?

Comment: Glad I could help :)
try replacing the `<div class="col-lg-7">` with `<div class="col-lg-12">`
refer to [link]http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid[link] and [link]https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/[link]
in col-lg-7 the lg represents large screen sizes and 7 is the number of columns. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all , try to use bootstrap classes rather than ur styles ,if they are not able to response u ,so use ur styles .
for floating , u can use , pull-left/right class , and for width , u do not need to use ur style , 100% of a div or an element is col-(xs/sm/md/lg)-12 , and it s from col-md-1 to 12 , use these classes instead of ur own styles .

bootstrap have clearfix like this : `<div class="clearfix"></div>`

Comment: I've realized that the css has really been my biggest pain point. Since posting, I've restarted from scratch using strictly bootstrap and everything is going much smoother. Thank you for the advise and for directing me to the clarify class.